# help to determine right path for site directory apache2

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2

This is my `.conf` file

```
  <VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
    ServerName  test.com
        ServerAdmin admin@test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it should after typing [test.com](http://test.com) it go directly to test.com directory , but it's show up this page

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   test.com/   2015-07-12 23:10    -    
[DIR]   test22.com/ 2015-07-12 22:55    -    
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at test.com Port 80
```

why this happen while i defined where test.com have to access in this line.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com
```

It's should show only the content of `test.com` directory not all directories , this is my problem :/

## So

I need this domain [test.com](http://test.com) access only this directory in this path

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com
```

Comment: Did you disable the default site before adding your own?

Comment: it's enabled right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tell us that you've made a virtualhost and the domain links to it this means there's not much wrong. Assuming you've only one domain your virtualhost is supposed to look like this:

    `ServerName www.test.com

    ServerAlias test.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/test.com"`

Comment: Thanks for answer , my problem is when type test.com it's not open the right path that i have determination at test.conf it show up  page with html Directory and than test.com directory, i son't want that happen this all i need

Comment: Just fo be sure: do you use www.test.com or just test.com. Those two are not nessecarily identical. Try both please and report the result. If both.give the same undesired result then please edit your question and show us the virtualhost declaration. Because I can't think of anything else which is possibly wrong.

Comment: Check it out i have edit the post

Comment: i get something  don't understand , that when i use my local ip it's work fine , but when i edit the .conf file and add my public ip , it's show up the list of directories again , is that matter ??

Comment: Your virtualhost declaration is wrong. You've to set it to *.80 because now it is listening to 192.168.1.10 port 80 which is your internal IP. Setting it to your external IP and port 80 works also. The declaration *.80 means it is listening on both the internal and external IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot this problem with more than a week , and the solution is only with this (*) , thanks :))

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes errors are very small :-). Thanks for accepting my answer. Can you please upvote it too, which earns me 10 extra reputation points?

Comment: Sure.. you just ask ;)